# Spaces in filepath cause multiple instances of my application to appear when executed via Windows Context Menu

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, contextmenu, command-line-arguments

I've created a WPF Form application that can be called via the Windows Context menu.  The application works great when I debug it.  When I deploy it and right click on a file, if it has any spaces in the path, it only reads the path up to the space, but opens up a window for each space in the path.  This is very annoying and I'm not sure how to fix this.

I've tried using Environment.GetCommandLineArgs() in my method as well as just using MainWindow(string filepath); both methods create the same problem.

This is a ClickOnce application so not sure if this would have anything to do with it, but I do capture the directory location of the executing assembly when it gets installed for the first time and have it update the registry in the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT*\shell[APP}\command key.  The default value is an expanded string with the location of the ClickOnce App executable and I have added "%1" so the filepath can be passed into it as an argument.

```
void checkRegistry()
{
    RegistryKey baseKey=Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey("*\\shell", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);

    //add the key
    RegistryKey menuKey=baseKey.CreateSubKey("GetCRC");
    menuKey.SetValue("", "Get CRC");

    //add the command key 
    RegistryKey commandKey = menuKey.CreateSubKey("command");
    string appfilePath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
    commandKey.SetValue("",String.Format("{0}\\GetCRC2.exe %1",appfilePath), RegistryValueKind.ExpandString);

    commandKey.Close();
    menuKey.Close();
    baseKey.Close();
}

public MainWindow(string filePath)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //check registry and add menu option 
    checkRegistry();
    var args = Environment.GetCommandLineArgs();
    if (args.Count() > 1)
    {
        this.filepath = args[1];
    }
    else
    {
        //run the file signatures
        this.filepath = filePath;
    }
    textboxFilePath.Text = filepath;
    calcSignatures();
}

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    //check registry and add menu option if it doesn't exist
    checkRegistry();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting quotes around application name and file name:

```
string.Format("\"{0}\\GetCRC2.exe\" \"%1\"",appfilePath)
```

Comment: Yep that did the trick.  I feel like a donkey for not realizing this on my own. Thanks, Athari.

Answer (score 0):

if the file is named "long hair"
args[1] will be "long" and args[2] will be "hair"

You should either input the filename in quotes or do something to deal with all the user input from the command line, like I dunno...

for args.length keep adding args and a space to the filename variable.

Sorry I'm not writing actual code, I barely know any c#